# In 8086 assembly, why and when is offset required in mov command?

Tags: assembly, offset, x86-16, intel-syntax

I want to know what is the difference between "`mov ax, offset new`" and "`mov ax, new`"

What offset actually does, which value it adds up?

Comment: You are not asking us to provide help during your exam, do you?

Comment: `mov ax, new` since _AX_ is a 16-bit register the 16-bit value stored at label `new` is moved into _AX_.. `mov ax, offset new` moves the **address** of `new` into _AX_

Comment: Thanks alot Sir... God bless you